# Is there a character or file size limit for tesseract-ocr output?

Tags: python-2.7, tesseract, raspberry-pi3

I am using raspberry pi 3B and python to do image processing on an image captured using raspberry pi camera. Here is the original image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxm5MQBqJ3WvMHB2VmdZdDByaXM

This is the image after rotating and cropping which is given as input to tesseract:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxm5MQBqJ3WvVU5hM2t6aFZ5RUE

After running tesseract-ocr, it recognizes about 2/3rd of the image with reasonable accuracy but totally leaves out the last part. Is this due to file size limitation or is there any other reason?

This is the text after running tesseract:

Instmrnentntlun is it collectIVe term for measuring instruments used for
indicating. measuring and recording physical quantities.

The term instrumentation may refer to something as simple as direct on
reading thermometers or. when using many sensors, may {mvmm
complex Industrial control system in such as manufacturing 1  ry, a". .
and transportation. lnstrutnentation can be found in the househo as w .

a smoke detector or a heating thermostat are examples.

In some cases the sensor is a very minor element of the mechanism. Digital
cameras and wristwatches might technically meet the loose definition of
instrumentation because they record and/or display sensed information. Under
most circumstances neither would be called instrumentation, but when used 
measure the elapsed time of a race and to document the winner at the ﬁnish line,
both would be called instrumentation.

Household

A very simple example of an instrumentation system is a

mechanical thermostat, used to control a household fumace and thus to control
room temperature. A typical unit senses temperature with a bi-metallic strip. It
displays temperature by a needle on the free end of the strip. It activates the
furnace by a mercury switch. As the switch is rotated by the strip, the mercury
makes physical (and thus electrical) contact between electrodes.

Another example of an instrumentation system is a home security system. Such
a system consists of sensors (motion detection, switches to detect door
openings), simple algorithms to detect intrusion, local control (arm/disarm) and

remote monitoring of the system so that the police can be summoned.
Communication is an inherent part ofthe design.

Automotive

Comment: If there is such a limitation, your image is definitely nowhere near it :) I think the remaining text is simply too skewed. Try manually deskewing the remaining text - and leave the rest of the image untouched. See if there is a different result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We found online that tesseract can manage a skew angle of about 10-15 degrees. That's why we never considered the necessity to de-skew. We'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: We cropped out the part and de-skewed it, the output has improved greatly. It was off by 2 degrees. We need to include de-skewing in our pre-processing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Added as answer. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is such a limitation, your image is definitely nowhere near it. I think the remaining text is simply too skewed. Try manually deskewing the remaining text - and leave the rest of the image untouched.

While tesseract should work even with much higher skew angles, the fact that the skew varies per paragraph (in your example) might make it leave out the final one.